# unable to solve the sql injection error while recieving data from url

Tags: php, mysql

php code

```
    <?php
    require_once "../model/db_helpers.php";
    $movie_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_GET['id']);
    //echo $movie_id;
    $watch=mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_GET['watch']);

    $result= $obj->select("movie_views","all_movies","movie_id='$movie_id'");

    //print_r($result);

    if($watch =="true")
    {
        $result[0]->movie_views ++;
        $movie_views= $result[0]->movie_views;
        $update= $obj->update("all_movies","movie_views='$movie_views'","movie_id='$movie_id'");

        //print_r($update);
    }

?>
<script>
    //window.location.href="showcontent.php?id=<?php echo $movie_id; ?>";
</script>
```

In the above code everything is functional except the update query. i need to update the link clicks into the database where i need to give the id (which is the data passed through the url) as the condition in the query.

I know i have to use mysqli_real_eascape_string to avoid sqlinjection error. but still i somehow get the following error.

**Error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

please provide an answer well explained about where i went wrong as i am new to the subject.

thank you.

Comment: FYI i have made separate functions for crud in the db_helpers files.

Comment: What SQL query does your db_helper generate?

Comment: function update($table,$records,$condition)
  {
   $sql="update $table set $records where $scondition";
   
   $result= mysqli_query($this->conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));
   
   echo "Update Successful";
  }

Comment: What's the point of escaping if you're just going to do `"movie_id='".$_GET['id']."'"` with the raw $_GET value? ANd why aren't you using prepared statements/bind variables?

Comment: @MarkBaker . sry i just changed that to check where is the error. the select function works. but as i add the update function. the error is show

Comment: I would follow @MarkBaker's advice and rewrite your code to use prepared statements/bind variables.

Comment: now i hav made the changes in the select query, still the error continues! :(

Comment: Output the actual SQL query that is being executed. We're just seeing a black box here with no way of knowing what's actually going on.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"  This is the only out put i am getting when i running this file!

Comment: So where's the code for `$obj->update()` that's the "black box" that we can't see inside

Comment: Not the error, we need to see the ***actual query*** you're trying to execute... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled variable name

change 
$sql="update $table set $records where **$scondition**" 
to 
$sql="update $table set $records where **$condition**"

So generated query is `update all_movies set movie_views='X' where"` 
which has no condition